# How to disable Eclipse IDE Language Server

Tags: eclipse

I am running Eclipse IDE
Version 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

On macOS Mojave
Version 10.14.1
MacBook Pro 2018 with 32GB and cpu 2.9 G i9

When I attempt to things such as open up a class file etc - I see the Initialize Language Server and I get the famous BeachBall - some times it is for a second or two and other times 30 or more seconds.

Is there some configuration or something that can improve the performance of this or ability to turn it off?  Search the web has turned up nothing so far.  At first I thought it was the freemarker IDE extension - uninstalled that but no change.

Comment: For what language? Every language server is different.

Comment: Which Eclipse package (_Eclipse IDE for ..._) do you have? Which additional plug-ins do you installed beside the Freemarker plug-in? What is in _Window > Preferences: Language Servers_?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660749/java-util-concurrent-executionexception-org-eclipse-lsp4j-jsonrpc-jsonrpcexcept/74660858#74660858

Comment: So there apprantly is a bug in the LanguageServer implementation in Eclipse, and upgradng to latest (STS 4.17 and above) shoudl fix this issue. Some intelligent people speaking here See Issue https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/568
See Issue https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/851
See Issue https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/925

Answer (score 27):

I uninstalled freemarker IDE and all the other JBOSS extensions since I am not currently using them.

I then when into Preferences -> Language Servers and turn them all off.

Now I do not have any issues with slowness of opening files or the famous mac BeachBall.

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was with Spring, and then I went ahead and turned off all Spring language servers. I do not know what capabilities are lost due to this, but there seems to be lot of improvement that is needed here before we actually use it.

What a pain in neck, killed my office work productivity for almost a month!

[image: Turning off Language server support]

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660749/java-util-concurrent-executionexception-org-eclipse-lsp4j-jsonrpc-jsonrpcexcept/74660858#74660858

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142014/slow-eclipse-spring-sts-plugin/75142105#75142105

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved in Eclipse 2022-12 (v4.26.0). Left the language servers enabled, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, you can turn off the language servers in Preferences -> Language Servers. However I've discovered you can actually turn them on again and they will likely have fixed themselves. Or at least that's what happens frequently to me.